# Winforms PropertyGrid - properties not editable

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, propertygrid

Hello this is my first question of stack overflow, so forgive me if i do anything stupid.
Well my problem is that I'm working on a level editor and i want to use a PropertyGrid control to edit properties of tiles/entities etc.. so everything works so far, the values show correctly, update when changed trough code but the problem i am expierencing is that I cannot change values unless it is a boolean, i googled alot but i simply could find no solutions.

Here is the code where i define the properties:

```
    [Description("Defines the Position on the screen")]
    public Vector2 screenpos { get;  set; }
    Vector2 WorldPos;
    [Description("Defines the texture of the selected tile")]
    public string texture { get;  set; }
    [Description("Defines if the player can collide with this tile")]
    public bool IsCollidable { get;  set; }
    [Description("Defines on what layer this tile is drawn (1-3)")]
    public int Layer { get;  set; }
    [Description("Shows if the tile is currently visible on the screen")]
    public bool OnScreen { get;  private set; }
```

I can edit the IsCollidable and if i remove the private from OnScreen's set i can edit that too but i can not edit anything else, oh and i would appriciate if you could word your answers a bit simpler i'm not that much of an expierenced programmer, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, i had this.KeyPreview = true; in my Form1 constructor, by removing that i could fix the issue.
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5):

Most standard types with a public property (that is read+write) should be editable.

If `Vector2` is fairly simple, and you just want it to expand in the `PropertyGrid`, then:

```
[Description("Defines the Position on the screen")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public Vector2 screenpos { get;  set; }
```

If `Vector2` is your own code, then you can also decorate `Vector2` *itself* and it will apply to all properties:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public {class|struct} Vector2 {...}
```

There is also a trick to do this for types *outside* of your control; at app startup, run:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(Vector2),
    new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom UI Type Editor for your `Vector2` class.

[Here's a tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> the problem i am expierencing is that I cannot change values unless it is a boolean

I don't see anything in your code which explains this. You do not need to do anything special to make `int` or `string` properties editable in a propertygrid, as demonstrated by this minimal example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication13
{
   static class Program
   {
      [STAThread]
      static void Main()
      {
         Application.EnableVisualStyles();
         Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
         Application.Run(new MainForm());
      }
   }

   public class Test
   {
      public string StringProperty { get; set; }
      public int IntProperty { get; set; }
      public bool BoolProperty { get; set; }
   }

   class MainForm : Form
   {
      public MainForm()
      {
         var propertyGrid = new PropertyGrid() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
         this.Controls.Add(propertyGrid);
         propertyGrid.SelectedObject = new Test();
      }
   }
}
```

I can edit all three properties with the above code. How did you determine that you "cannot change values"? What are you seeing exactly?

Comment: I see them like a regular property grid, not grayed out anything i can move the text cursor and stuff too but if i type (letters or numbers) nothing happens.